# React setState not triggering automatic update when called within a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native

I'm building an app with React Native, fairly new to the technology.

I understand that `setState` is asynchronous, and that it can batch updates for performance reasons.

The issue I'm having is this, `setState` is not triggering an update after calling it inside a callback, which gets executed after my API call has been made.

I don't mean immediately, I mean indefinitely - IF I do not touch the screen.

Following the code below, there is a prop on state called "foo", this is set to some default value when the component mounts.

I press the "Upload" button (see below), this triggers the API call, this is represented by the "upload" function below. In the success callback of this API call I then call `this.setState`.. and changed the value of the prop 
"foo".

After I press upload, if I leave my device on the desk for 10 seconds, 1 minute, 10 minutes, the component's `componentDidUpdate` method is never called. However, if I press the screen / touch a button, etc., after the API call has been made, the state is changed, `componentDidUpdate` is called.

Am I missing a trick here? This seems like weird behaviour.

The API call in this example is completing in less than 1 second. Again, if I leave the device on the desk for 10 minutes, `componentDidUpdate` does not get fired - as soon as I touch the screen / some UI element, `componentDidUpdate` gets called.

Example code below.

```
class SomeComponent extends Component { 

    ...

    componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({ foo: "Hello, world."});    
    }

    componentDidUpdate () {
        console.log("Component updated.");
    }

    upload (files) {
        Upload.upload(files, (res) => {
            //Success uploading file.


            //Clear pendingFiles
            this.setState({
                foo: "bar"
            });


        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Errorz");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render () {
           return ( 
               <View>
                   <Button onPress={() => { this.upload(); }} 
                           title="Upload"> 

                         <Text>Upload</Text>
                   </Button>

                   <Text>{this.state.foo}</Text> 
               </View>
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you remembering to bind `upload` in the constructor? `this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);`? (just throwing stuff at the wall here)

Comment: do you have any errors on the console?

Comment: No errors in the console, as soon as I touch the screen the statement 'Component updated.' is logged to the screen as expected

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc this is correctly bound to the function, i'm using an arrow function in the onPress property of the button instead of bind

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. Overlooked that. I normally use the bind because it's a bit easier on memory usage (you're not making as many closures).

Comment: @LeeBrindley You can put a callback in `setState` that will run after it's done. You could throw a console out in there to see if for some reason the `setState` is just sitting the the queue and not being run.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc I have done this also, it does not get logged until I click the screen.. *scratches head

Comment: @LeeBrindley can you create a jsbin replicating the issue? I don't see anything wrong with that code, perhaps is in the part of the code you are not showing O.o